# Can a student visa holder in New Zealand apply for a visitor visa to Australia while still in New Zealand?

Tags: visas, australia, residency

Can a student visa holder to NZ get a visitor visa to Australia from NZ (Indian passport holder)?

Comment: Yes. Try this link and get more information you need will be available. http://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1

Answer (score 2):

If you're a resident in New Zealand, you *must* apply for visas from New Zealand. So **yes**, you can get a visitor visa to Australia from New Zealand.